# Fetching via a join table as if it was a to-one relationship via Doctrine ORM

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, junction-table

I'm trying to represent a "family" structure in a flexible manner where I can store all manner of links between two people, but primarily family relationships ("spouse", "parent", "child").

#### My drastically simplified schema:

I have a `people` table, simplified just to:

- `id` [pk, auto inc]
- `forenames` [varchar]
- `surname` [varchar]

and a 'people_relationships' table:

- `id` [pk, auto inc]
- `person_id` [int]
- `relationship_id` [int]
- `type` ['spouse', 'parent', 'child', etc]

`person_id` and `relationship_id` both map to `id` on the `person` table. Two entries are stored in the person_relationships table, one for each direction.
The above were created by the `make:entity` in Symfony, so I also have a `fetchRelationships()` method. All good so far.

#### However...

Given a person can only have one father and one mother, I'd like to be able to simply do:

```
<?php
$person->getFather(); // or getMother
```

which would resolve ONE instance of `Person` that would be the father or mother (or NULL if not set).

#### What I already think might work, but not quite what I'm after:

1. I'm aware that I could add a `father_id` and `mother_id` on the person and literally maintain a one-to-one relation, and (via getters/setters) perhaps also keep an entry inside of `person_relationships`.
2. I'm also aware that I could probably create these getters and just loop the results of `getRelationships` and return the one that matches. And the setters, too.

#### And so..

I just wondered whether there was a simpler way; with DQL or raw SQL, I could just add an extra condition on the JOIN such as `type = "parent"`. I just don't see how this might be done via entity attributes/annotations. And from what I've read (and digested with my fairly limited knowledge of Doctrine) it doesn't appear to be possible.

And I'm also wondering whether I can ALSO do away with the need for storing each direction in the relationships table? In theory, I only need a `type` of 'parentchild' and then just use person_id as the parent, relationship_id as the child, etc.

Any help would be much appreciated!